# Disable rotation of mkannotationview when map is rotated or tilted - swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have an app that has a original bearing for cars, but when I tilt or rotate the map , it follows, I dont want that behavior. I want some behavior that the annotaion view does not tilt nor rotate with the map.

In google map you only have to set this to false [Flat or Billboard orientation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#flatten_a_marker)

Is there the same sample here in `MKAnnotationView` or `MKPinAnnotationView`?

Comment: Not as far as I know. I would overlay a transparent UIView with the same frame, but maybe someone knows a better way.

Comment: @Grimxn thanks for pointing out. I hope somebody has a different solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this by reversing the angle of the rotation on the annotations:

```
func mapViewDidChangeVisibleRegion(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
       for annotation: MKAnnotation? in mapView.annotations {
           var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?
           if let anAnnotation = annotation {
               annotationView = mapView.view(for: anAnnotation)
           }
           let headingInRadians = mapView.camera.heading * Double.pi / 180
           annotationView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -headingInRadians)
       }
    }
```